# How to initialize structure in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am using a C-style structure which does not have any constructor, like this:

```
struct structName {
    int  mem1;
    int  mem2;
    char mem3;
    char mem4;
}
```

I am creating a variable of this structure and I want to initialize all members of the structure to zero.  I found the following methods.

1. ```
   struct structName structVar = {};
   ```
2. ```
   struct structName structVar = {0};
   ```
3. ```
   struct structName structVar = struct structName();
   ```

For the first two methods, my compiler is giving "missing initializer for member" warning.

The third approach compiles without warnings.

- Is it a valid C++ statement?
- Am I missing some genuine warning/error by using method 3?
- Is there any better alternative method, apart from memset()?

Comment: @101010 No, not necessarily. `struct foo { foo()=default; foo(int){} };`.

Comment: And what does your structure look like? Does it have any constructors? Destructors?

Comment: In C++ you do not need to write `struct` there at all, so I wonder what resource you found when you "searched on internet". Prefer learning C++ from a good book...

Comment: @lightness-races-in-orbit, ok, I can remove "struct". But I am more interested about the initialization.

Comment: @joachim-pileborg, my structure has no constructor/ destructor. It has some int and char members.

Comment: `= {};` is the best way. You could disable that warning. Preferable to mangling your code.

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://ideone.com/G8G9G2). Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: @MayurK: I understand that but it's a warning flag about what resources you're using, which is important.

Comment: Is this line `struct structName structVar = struct structName();` really legal?

Comment: @Carousel, Sorry for the confusion. I have a .cpp file with C-style coding. `struct structName structVar = struct structName();` is not allowed in C but is allowed in C++.

Comment: Speaking of [learning C++ from a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred method should be one of:

```
structName structVar{};
structName structVar = {};
auto structName = structVar{};
```

<sub>there are subtle differences, but not for aggregates as in your example</sub>

This has the added advantage that it initializes `structVar` for **any type** of `structName` or if it cannot perform an initialization it makes the program ill-formed (the code doesn't compile) (plus it doesn't allow narrowing).

In your specific example, `structName` is an agregate:

[C++14 draft standard:](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)

> §8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> (1) An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3)

The initialization syntax I used is called List-initialization:

> §8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]
>
> (1) List-initialization is
>   initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list.
>   [...] An initializer list may be empty. [...]

For our aggregate this means:

> §8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr]
>
> (2) When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as
>   specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer list are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause
>
> (7) If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are
>   members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized
>   shall be initialized from its brace-or-equal-initializer or, if there
>   is no brace-or-equalinitializer, from an empty initializer list
>   (8.5.4).
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct S { int a; const char* b; int c; int d = b[a]; };
> S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
> ```
>
> initializes ss.a with 1, ss.b with "asdf", ss.c with the value of an
>   expression of the form **int{} (that is, 0)**, and ss.d with the value
>   of ss.b[ss.a] (that is, ’s’)
>
> [...]
>
> end example ]

So all of these are valid and do the exact same thing:

```
structName structVar = {};
structName structVar = {0};
structName structVar = {0, 0};
```

However if there is at least one `initializer-clauses` and less than there are members in the aggregate, `gcc` and `clang` emit a warning. It might be that you intended to initialize all members, but missed some. So the empty initializer list is the safest choice.

---

As a side note `struct` is not needed and universally not used in a declaration. So replace this:

```
struct structName structVar
```

with:

```
structName structVar
```